# SQL import wizard drops leading zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel, import

I've read all the posts about prefixing the numbers with ', and setting IMEX=1 in the connection string; nothing seems to do the trick for me.

Here's the setup: Excel column with mixed data - 99% numbers (some start with 0) 1% text.

PROGRAMATICALLY mporting into SQL Server 2005 table / column type - varchar(255).

**Import works fine locally, but once i move the code to production (GoDaddy), it drops the leading 0's in the column.**

Any ideas?

p.s. I knew about the registry change solution, matter of fact - the value was set to 0 on my dev box, but the answer made me realize that the value wasn't set on the PRODUCTION SERVER :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISAM driver only samples the first 8 rows, but you can change that behaviour through a registry change:

http://sqlserversd.wordpress.com/2008/09/14/ssis-excel-values-import-as-nulls/

But yes, using Excel for machine-to-machine data transfer is a nightmare...Is there no other way you can be sent the data?

Comment: even though i had that value changed in the registry, this answer made me realize that the value on PRODUCTION SERVER wasn't changed :)

Comment: Now that made me lol, the typical 'But it works on my machine' problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The Excel driver only sample the 1st 8 rows to determine the data type.
This means that it assumes the column is numeric is "bob" does not appear in rows 1 to 8.

The target table column datatype is irrelevant.

Ths issue has been there for a [long time](http://forums.xmetal.com/index.php?topic=21.0), I saw it in 2003 the first time.

[BOL notes on excel import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We usually save the file as a .csv file or .txt file and then the issue doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick and tricky way for this. following these steps BUT first copy all the data / columns and rows from the actual excel sheet into another excel sheet just to be of the safe side so that you have the actual data to compare with.

Steps:

1. Copy all the values in the column and paste them into a notepad.
2. Now change the column type to text in the Excel sheet (it will trim the preceding / trailing Zeros), don't worry about that.
3. Go to Notepad and copy all the values that you have pasted just now.
4. Go to your excel sheet and paste the values in same column.

If you have more than one column with 0 values then just repeat the same.
Now your excel document is ready to be imported with Zero Values :).

Happy Days.